# csv to txt python conversion script leaves file with 0 bytes

Tags: python, csv, ssis

I have a SSIS Loop package that is calling a python script multiple times.

#### The intent:

There is a folder of csv files.  I need them converted to pipe-delimited text files.  Some of the files have bad rows in them.  The python script converts the csv files into the pipe files while removing the bad records.

#### the python code:

```
import csv
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print(sys.argv)
    sys.exit("usage: python csvtopipe.py <<SOURCE.csv>> <<TARGET.txt>>  <<number of columns>>")

source = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
colcount = sys.argv[3]

file_comma =  open(source, "r", encoding="unicode_escape")
reader_comma = csv.reader(file_comma, delimiter=',')
file_pipe = open(target, 'w', encoding="utf-8")
writer_pipe = csv.writer(file_pipe, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
for row in reader_comma:
    if len(row) == int(colcount):
        print("write this..")
        writer_pipe.writerow(row)
file_pipe.close()
file_comma.close()
```

#### The SSIS Package:

[image]
[image]

#### The python call from SSIS:

```
python csvtopipe.py <<SOURCE.csv>> <<TARGET.txt>>  <<number of columns>>
```

#### The problem.

The loop works correctly, but when the individual call finishes, the file re-writes to 0 bytes. I can't tell if it's a SSIS problem or a python problem.

THanks!

## UPDATE 1

This is the original version of the code.  same result:

```
import csv
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print(sys.argv)
    sys.exit("usage: python csvtopipe.py <<SOURCE.csv>> <<TARGET.txt>>  <<number of columns>>")

source = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
colcount = sys.argv[3]

with open(source, "r", encoding="unicode_escape") as file_comma:
    reader_comma = csv.reader(file_comma, delimiter=',')
    with open(target, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file_pipe:
        writer_pipe = csv.writer(file_pipe, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in reader_comma:
            if len(row) == int(colcount):
                print("write")
                writer_pipe.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I would recommend you update to use `with open(......) as ...` instead of separate `open()` and `close()`. In the event of a problem, this will ensure the file is closed.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I did try that first. Same result.  I added THAT code to the main question.  Maybe it'll open up something for you.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: I assume you are seeing `write` in the output. You could display the file size before exiting (see `os.path.getsize()`)

Comment: I am seeing write in stdout.  that's the first sign of seeing something wrong.

Comment: I tried `os.path.getsize()` on the target file, and I'm getting stdout filesize correctly, but when the next execution happens, it goes back to 0.

Comment: Try appending a timestamp to the output filename

Comment: it looks like it's writing to the file two or three times.  then zeroes them.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ok. that worked.  why did it work?

Comment: Is it possible the script is being executed multiple times at the same time? You might want to consider a `singleton pattern`. i.e. ensuring only one copy runs at a time.

Comment: ok.  what is a singleton pattern and where do I find out how to use it?  Thanks!

Comment: I've not needed to do it yet in Python so don't know the best approach, it can depend on which OS you are on. It is a way to ensure that only one instance of your script can be run at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would switch to using `with open()...` rather then separate `open()` and `close()` functions. This will help to ensure that the file is automatically closed in the event of a problem.

As the script is being invoked multiple times, I would add a timestamp to your output filename. This would help to ensure that each time it is run, a different file is produced.

Lastly, you could add a test to ensure that only one copy of the script is executed at the same time. For Windows based applications this can be done using a Windows Mutex. On Linux, the use of a file lock can be used. This approach is sometimes referred to as the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
import win32event
import win32api
from winerror import ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import sys
import os
import time

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print(sys.argv)
    sys.exit("usage: python csvtopipe.py <<SOURCE.csv>> <<TARGET.txt>>  <<number of columns>>")

# Wait up to 30 seconds for another copy of the script to stop running
windows_mutex = win32event.CreateMutex(None, False, 'CSV2PIPE')
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(windows_mutex, 30000)

source = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]
colcount = sys.argv[3]

# Add a filestamp
path, ext = os.path.splitext(target)
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d %H%M_%S")
target = f'{path}_{timestamp}{ext}'

with open(source, "r", encoding="unicode_escape") as file_comma, \
    open(target, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file_pipe:

    reader_comma = csv.reader(file_comma, delimiter=',')
    writer_pipe = csv.writer(file_pipe, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')

    for row in reader_comma:
        if len(row) == int(colcount):
            print("write this..")
            writer_pipe.writerow(row)
```

Comment: instead of erroring out, is there a way to wait 5 seconds and try again?

Comment: Yes, `WaitForSingleObject()` could be used.

Comment: This is perfection! Thank you so much Martin!